Earth Engine addLayer takes forever
I'm new to Earth Engine, but I've been trying to plot a map with a SENTINEL-2 image, like this:
import ee
import geemap
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd


GEE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "xxxx"
GEE_CREDENTIALS = "yyy.json"
service_account = GEE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, GEE_CREDENTIALS)
ee.Initialize(credentials)


gdf = gpd.read_file('data.shp')

fc_reg = geemap.geopandas_to_ee(gdf)


start_date = '2023-10-01'  
end_date = '2023-10-01'  
first_feature = fc_reg.first()
first_geometry = first_feature.geometry()
image_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') \
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date) \
    .filterBounds(first_geometry) \
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')  # Sort by least cloudy

image = image_collection.first()

vis_params = {
    'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],  # True color composite (RGB)
    'min': 0,
    'max': 3000,
    'gamma': 1.4
}

map = geemap.Map(center=[gdf.geometry.iloc[0].bounds[1], 
                            gdf.geometry.iloc[0].bounds[0]], zoom=12)

map.addLayer(image, vis_params, 'Sentinel-2 Image')
map.addLayerControl()

The problem is, every object created from first_feature is impossible to open. The console tries to load it but it never ends. So these all fail to run:
first_feature

first geometry

map

After some patience I'm getting the following error:
EEException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.

supposedly I'm downloading a very small image so why would this happen? the polygon has 254 exterior points, 0 interior points and it's less than 1km2.
